# Show element when radio is checked

Tags: html, css

just trying to make a `p` element to show when `input[type=radio]` is checked

the html code:

```
<div class="form-group checkbox">
    <input type="radio" id="pago-deposito" name="[transaccion]pago"/>
    <label for="pago-deposito">check1</label>
    <p id="pago-hint">
        //hints
    </p>
</div>
```

the CSS i have tried

```
.checkbox > input#pago-deposito[type=radio]:checked + p#pago-hint{
    display: block;
}

#pago-hint{
    display: none;
    line-height: 40px;  
}
```

so that's it, i have implemented the same method in a different place and it works, i just don't know why this one doesn't

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the [general sibling selector (`~`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) rather than the [adjacent sibling selector(`+`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) as `#pago-hint` does not immediately follow your radio button:

```css
.checkbox > input#pago-deposito[type=radio]:checked ~ p#pago-hint{
    display: block;
}

#pago-hint{
    display: none;
    line-height: 40px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group checkbox">
    <input type="radio" id="pago-deposito" name="[transaccion]pago"/>
    <label for="pago-deposito">check1</label>
    <p id="pago-hint">
        //hints
    </p>
</div>
```